# how to get more than one value in sql server stored procedure variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
declare @Pipno varchar(500)
select @Pipno = (V_3) from REPORTDATE // here V-3 contain more than five rows
select @Pipno
```

but in select @Pipno prints only one row (i.e., max of V_3)
i want to store all five or more rows in this @Pipno variable please reply me

Answer (score 5):

You can use a table variable.

```
declare @Pipno table(V_3 varchar(500))

insert into @Pipno
select V_3 
from REPORTDATE

select V_3
from @Pipno
```

Or if you want the result as one string.

```
declare @Pipno varchar(500)
set @Pipno = ''

select @Pipno = @Pipno + V_3 + ' '
from REPORTDATE

select @Pipno
```